# Windows Form Application (VB) - Dataview reading in txt file sizing

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a windows form application to create a small backup program (I'm a student and this is basically a make work project) Anyways, I got it working but my datagrid view isn't displaying the way I want it too. It's not auto-sizing so it looks pretty terrible. I have my datagridview reading in a .txt. Here's my code;

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Code\filenames.txt"
    Dim dtTest As New DataTable("dtTest")

    dtTest.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))

    Try
        Dim reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filename)
        reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        reader.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not reader.EndOfData
            Dim Fields() As String = reader.ReadFields
            dtTest.Rows.Add(Fields)
        End While

        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
    End Try

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTest.DefaultView
End Sub
```

But it's displaying as a really small box inside the larger datagridview. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain "really small" box and exactly what you want to see.

Comment: This is too small http://postimage.org/image/4zuvmal0n/ this is what I want it to look like http://postimage.org/image/4haex8ndj/ right now I have to manually increase the columns size after the program starts running.

Comment: I can't access postimage at work, but have you tried setting `AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Width of the column to the width of the control minus the width of the select box things to the left of the column (syntax might be off, tested in C# and tried to VB-ize):

```
dtTest.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
dtTest.Columns("Col1").Width = dtTest.Width - dtTest.RowHeadersWidth
```

Might also need to tweak with an additional -1 or -2 to make it skinny enough to avoid getting a horizontal scroll bar. Past that if your dialog and control are resizable you can add an event handler when the form size changes to call that line of code again and keep the column set to 100% of the width.

EDIT: For future readers, see comments below for a better way to do this.

Comment: Your way works so thank-you. However, I did find a seperate way to do it as well; 

DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

Comment: I didn't notice the AutoSizeColumnsMode property. I knew about the Width property and worked my way out from there. AutoSizeColumnsMode is definitely better for your purposes.